# Морфология

Tags: морфология

Здравствуйте!"Цап" какая часть речи?

Comment: "... Он её голубушку шмяк-шмяк-шмяк-шмяк. Ам-ням-ням-ням, да и шмыг-шмыг-шмыг-шмыг."

Answer (score 3):

Междометная глагольная форма: бах, бряк, прыг, скок, шасть, шмыг, цап  и прочие.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, Людмила!!!я так и думала,просто один человек обвинил меня в некомпетентности.А в какой литературе это можно прочитать, чтобы показать.в учебнике 7 класса этого слова нет, а для доказательства правоты, мне сказали,принести книгу!!!подскажите.дело чести!!!

Answer (score 2):

Можете прочитать здесь:http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/266/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5